# Can't resolve reference while using Spring EL

Tags: spring, el

What I am trying to do is to create a Struts base action that initializes a logging proxy. All services called by any action will use this proxy to log errors. The proxy is then accessed by an interceptor that then does the actual logging.  Everything compiles, builds.  However deployment I get the following error on Tomcat 7:

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journalVoucherService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '#{baseAction.logger}' while setting bean property 'logger'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.blah.logging.LoggingProxy@58edf4c8' is defined`

Here's my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Needed to run @PostConstruct initialization checking methods -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Needed for @Transactional annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Journal Voucher Service -->
    <bean id="journalVoucherService"
class="com.blah.service.impl.JournalVoucherServiceImpl"
        parent="baseService">
    </bean>

    <!-- Base Service -->
    <bean id="baseService" abstract="true"
        class="com.blah.service.impl.BaseServiceDatabaseImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="logger" ref="#{baseAction.logger}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Loggging Proxy -->
    <bean id="loggingProxy" class="com.blah.logging.LoggingProxy"/>

    <!-- Struts 2 Actions -->
    <bean id="baseAction"
        class="com.blah.action.BaseAction">
        <property name="logger" ref="loggingProxy" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

It's probably something pretty simple but am new to Spring EL.

Comment: Have you tried `${baseAction.logger}`? Also its not clear where/how you are importing that value from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When I make this change I get Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journalVoucherService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '${baseAction.logger}' while setting bean property 'logger'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${baseAction.logger}' is defined
..... Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${baseAction.logger}' is defined

Comment: When you say where I am I importing value from I am not doing explicit import.  Maybe that is my problem.. How should I include that import in my application file?

Comment: One way is via properties file: `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myApp.properties" />` but not sure that will work here? You'll need to go back to your original source for that code I think.

Comment: I dont't think that properties can be resolved with Spring EL at all - consider using Spring 3.1 profiles.

Comment: The properties approach did not work in this case as EL did not recognize the reference.  It is doing string subsitution vs. eval.  I will take a look at profiles.  It seems that is a closer match to what I am trying to do.  Another approach is to use annotations in my class and then have autowire discovery find the bean reference and then us it in the xml.

Comment: I found the answer from SpringSource.  Can't use ref to inject the bean value; must use value.  This works: <property name="logger" value="#{baseAction.logger}">

Answer (score 0):

The logger property needed to be passed a value:

```
<bean id="baseService" abstract="true"
    <class="com.blah.service.impl.BaseServiceDatabaseImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="logger" value="#{baseAction.logger}" />
 </bean>
```